# Filter for Standard Campaign look up on Campaign Member

Tags: administration

I need to add specific type of campaign to Lead.

Is there a way to put filter on Campaign lookup in CampaignMember object. (Without customizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible AFAIK. You will need to 'customize' :)